# How to hide False value if not true

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have the following formula, I want to hide the `false` value appears in cell when no data available or when blank.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("6021",C25)),(Value!$M$4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `IF`'s 3rd argument, and set it to nothing (`""`):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("6021",C25)),(Value!$M$4), "")
```

Comment: But what if i have multiple Formula Values,  Like   =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("6021",C9)),(Value!$G$4),
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("7037",C9)),(Value!$G$5),))